# Using AuthBearerAuthentication in MVC6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am upgrading the app to ASP.NET MVC6 Beta 8.

Beta 7 had the `Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer` package. I can't find a Beta 8 version. Which Nuget package can I use for Beta 8?

Do we have the ASP.NET Authentication samples for Beta 8?

Thanks,
Sambath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue 413 on aspnet/Security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/413) asks to rename `OAuthBearer`. According to the [related pull request](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/422) it looks like it got renamed to `JwtBearer`.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into JwtBearer.

Comment: Changing to JwtBearer worked without any issues. Thanks for your help.